# How to prevent submit by double click

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I created **signup form** using with `ActiveForm` in yii2, by **double click**, form submits, it submits automaticaly. How do I prevent it, I want form submit just by click on submit button.

why this happens and what's the solution?

This is my form code:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]);
?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'nickname', ['addon' => ['prepend' => ['content' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>']]])->label(false)->textInput()?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'phone_number', ['addon' => ['prepend' => ['content' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>']]])->label(false)->textInput()?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'email', ['addon' => ['prepend' => ['content' => '@']]])->label(false)->textInput()?>
<?=$form->field($model, 'password', [
    'addon' => ['prepend' => ['content' => '<i class="fa fa-key"></i>']]])->passwordInput(['autocomplete' => 'off'])->label(false)->passwordInput();
?>
<div class="form-group">
<?=Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Signup'), ['value' => 'signupp', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signupButton', 'style' => 'width:100%;'])?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

Comment: Onclick you could disable the button with JS.

Comment: @JonStirling what happens if I disable the buton?

Comment: @JonStirling I want submit form by button.

Comment: Yeah, so on submit (i.e. clicking the submit button) immediately disable it so they can't click it a second time. Disabling it stops it from being clickable.

Comment: so are you trying to submit the form via ajax while disabling the button or normal submission?

Comment: after the update your question is different than before, you should not change the question like this , always edit the question and add the new information in the end with EDIT title , as this makes my answer look irrelevant. Are you saying that the form is submitting when you double-click on the button and not with a single-click ? if that is so then you might need to add any javascript used with your view form, add the complete view file from top to bottom,

Comment: add your related controller action code.

Comment: added and answer see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ActiveForm`'s js event `beforeSubmit` to disable the button at the time the form is submitted, you can use CSS `pointerEvents:'none'` to disable the click on the button.

Assing an `id="my-form"` to your form and `id="my-submit"` to your submit button and use the below script on top of your view and your button will be disabled at the time of submission.

```
$js =<<< JS
        $("#my-form").on("beforeSubmit",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#my-submit").css({pointerEvents:'none'});
            return true;
        });

JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```